# Replacing my failure æøå chars to æøå in MySQL or PHP cde

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so I have been storing wrong characters in my database in many rows, and under many columns and tables..

So this means that example "Æ" has turned out to be "&aelig;". I have fixed my server side code to show Æ and not to convert the encoding, but now it shows the actual "&aelig;".

So I will need to replace all my entrys that has "&aelig;" to "æ".

What are the best solution of doing this?

Can i do some operation direct in my database, that finds all "&aelig;" and replaces with "æ" ?

Or maybe a php code?

Or should i code one my self, I have thought about grabbing all rows in a table, looping through them, replace and run update query for each and one of them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing going through all records and using `html_entity_decode()` on them is your best bet. Otherwise, sure enough you could do an UPDATE that replaces specific strings in all rows, but it might not be all that easy if you want to replace all html entities.

EDIT: Make sure not to call `html_entity_decode()` on the same data twice... in most cases it will not matter, but there are circumstances in which it will.

Comment: so you say where I am outputting my stuff i should have html_entity_decode() ? Yeah i know it wont be a easy task to replace all html entities that are current stored, but i need to and prefer to just want to ask for best way(maybe theres easier way)

Comment: @Karem no what I meant was to fetch all the rows in your database and call `html_entity_decode()` on the fields that you want to "fix". And then update the database with the results. Otherwise, if you have already stored everything in your database with html entities encoded, then there is no need to call htmlentities/htmlspecialchars when outputting (although it would be better to just fix the data in the database in my opinion).

Comment: @Karem precisely, however, you must escape the strings with `mysql_real_escape_string()` before you put them back into the database or you could be in for a nasty surprise. Also `''` around the variables in the query string.

Comment: I wrote this quick example, so we could understand eachother, thats why no security and some syntax fails.. But ok great!

Comment: @Karem Great, just make sure to do a backup before you do this in the event that you mess up somewhere... although I'm guessing you've already done it ;)